# Como saber o conteúdo de uma chave estrangeira para o preenchimento de uma outra tabela?

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, modelagem

Darei como exemplo 2 tabelas de um banco de dados: Usuário e Endereço. 
onde o usuário tem o atributo idEndereco como chave estrangeira da tabela endereço. Os ids estão com AUTO INCREMENT, ainda sim, como faço pra saber qual o valor da chave estrangeira do endereço? Terei que fazer o insert em endereço, e depois fazer um select pra poder conseguir a sua chave primária? Há um método mais eficaz?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que vc quer, poderia ser mais especifico? Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) também para aprender mais sobre o site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela lógica você teria que inserir primeiramente o registro na tabela endereço. Com o comando `$mysqli->insert_id` você tem acesso ao último id inserido no último insert que você fez, isso caso esteja usando mysqli para fazer a conexão com o banco. Caso seja PDO, faça: `PDO::lastInsertId`. Se entendi direito, isso resolve seu problema.

Comment: Valeu, Simão. Era isso mesmo.